# Contradictory information in about page

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the about page, it says that "best practices" are both on topic (first bullet) and off topic (also first bullet).  It seems a little contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the "Ask about" section to:

> The quality of your working code with regards to:
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage

And the "Don't ask" section to:

> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")

Hopefully this clears up any confusion. If there's anything left unclear or anything that could be phrased better, I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic needs to be updated. I think the first part in the brackets of don't ask is better in the "Ask about section". It led to some confusion http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/confusion-with-factory-pattern-regarding-liskovs-substitution-principle-code-m?noredirect=1#comment48228_30343

Comment: @AseemBansal I've updated the "Don't ask" section on that page, so it's now the same as the "Don't ask" section on the About page. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

[The page you're referencing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about) says (emphasis mine):

> Ask about...
>
> - Best practices and design pattern **usage**
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews

I think what this means is that it's okay to ask about the usage of best practices *in a specific piece of code*, but it's not okay to ask about best practices in general.

This wording is certainly very confusing. Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: Maybe "Usage of best practices and design patterns"?

Answer (score 0):

In **what can be asked** it should be

- Usage of best practices and design pattern

In **what cannot be asked** it should be

- Various tools and practices
- Improving or conducting code reviews

Breaking it down into 2 points should be better

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify. Your proposed rewording just seems to slightly rearrange the sentences. I'm not seeing how they help deal with the actual issue raised.

Comment: Is the "best practices" in what cannot be asked about the various best-practices in a field? If yes, I'll edit my question with better wording. Also what is the part not being cleared by this rearrangement. Any example?

Comment: You can ask, "is my piece of code using best practices", but you can't ask "what are the best practices for doing X". I'm not sure your proposed working gets that across better.